# Host react static files on existing nginx separate directory

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-location

I want to host react build in `/v2` folder of my existing web app, but 404 page or blank page is shown the files are loaded as seen 200 in network but still page shows blank on loading `/v2`
have added a homepage field in package.json 
`"homepage": "/v2/"`. Also, have added `/v2` in routes.js redirect component.
My Nginx rule is

```
location ^~ /v2 {
     alias /Data/react/admin-src/build;
     index index.html;
     try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
```

Nginx also has existing PHP rules.

these changes are done in routes.js

```
<RedirectComponent to="/v2/auth/login" />
const RedirectComponent = ({to = '/v2/404'}) => <Redirect to={to} />;
<RedirectComponent to="/v2/" />
```

Comment: The last element of the `try_files` statement is a URI, so should be `/v2/index.html`

Comment: It still is redirected to the 404 page with all CSS JS loading but any link is routing to the 404 page.